# Case Statement Error when using MINUS Snowflake DB

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I´m trying to change a specific date to a other one in order to compare the hash values of two queries.
For that I´m using the CASE statement. But I can´t understand why I´m getting the following error

The column DATE_VALUE has the data type DATE and I´m operating on a Snowflake Database

```
inconsistent data type for result columns for set operator input branches, expected DATE, got BOOLEAN for expression [{2}] branch {3}
```

SQL statement

```
SELECT
  COL
, CASE 
    WHEN DATE_VALUE = '2021-01-10'
    THEN DATE_VALUE = CAST('2021-01-11' AS DATE)
END AS DATE_VALUE
,HASH(
CASE 
    WHEN DATE_VALUE = '2021-01-10'::DATE
    THEN DATE_VALUE= '2021-01-11'::DATE 
END 
, COL
, COL
, COL
, COL
, COL
, COL
, COL
)
FROM TABLE1 
MINUS
SELECT
COL
,   DATE_VALUE
,   HASH(
DATE_VALUE
, COL
, COL
, COL
, COL
, COL
, COL
, COL
)
FROM TABLE2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this expression for the second column:

```
(CASE WHEN DATE_VALUE = '2021-01-10'
      THEN DATE_VALUE = CAST('2021-01-11' AS DATE)
 END) AS DATE_VALUE
```

The `THEN` clause is:

```
DATE_VALUE = CAST('2021-01-11' AS DATE)
```

This is a boolean expression, not a date expression.  You seem to want:

```
(CASE WHEN DATE_VALUE = '2021-01-10'
      THEN CAST('2021-01-11' AS DATE)
 END) AS DATE_VALUE
```

Or:

```
(CASE WHEN DATE_VALUE = '2021-01-10'
      THEN '2021-01-11'::DATE
 END) AS DATE_VALUE
```

Answer (score 1):

`CASE..WHEN` is incorrect.

It should be

```
CASE 
    WHEN DATE_VALUE = '2021-01-10'
    THEN CAST('2021-01-11' AS DATE) -- DATE_VALUE = CAST('2021-01-11' AS DATE) returns boolean not date
END AS DATE_VALUE
```

Comment: Sorry, I can´t follow you. Do you mean the explicit 'DATE_VALUE' after the THEN statement?

Comment: Your query uses `THEN DATE_VALUE = CAST('2021-01-11' AS DATE)` while the answer in my query uses `THEN CAST('2021-01-11' AS DATE)`. Your query returns boolean and my query returns a date